# How can I enable shutdown verbosity?

Tags: shutdown, systemd

Already set the `/etc/default/grub` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but shutdown screen still blank. Trying to set it with verbose text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some boot-up and shutdown configurations were scrambled during one installation which was set to install recovery options on additional software among others installations tryouts.

Those unwanted software part was installed on /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu directory at / (root partition). This was causing recovery booting option to open a pink/purple recovery menu, with some non-working functions.

And, i think, it was somehow causing the non-verbosity on shutdown process despite enabling it on /etc/default/grub.

Afterall, the additional software menu looks to have several non-working options and i think some of them should be removed or fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply the changed settings with **grub-install** ?

What options did you use exactly? I think you must remove **quiet** and add **nosplash** to see messages during bootup.

The messages are also written to the system logs ind **/var/log/*.log** in nearly any case. Depending on your ubuntu version the filenames may vary. In my case (15.10) the names are **kern.log** and **system.log**

Comment: Yes, applied the changed settings. Already removed quiet, it's working fine on bootup, the problem is on shutdown. Strange thing is that other machine with same ubuntu version is working fine.